# Web Browser in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am building a windows phone app.I'm using **WebBrowser** in my app.
I want to know,what is the version of the Internet Explorer loaded, when I use **WebBrowser** in Windows Phone App?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In Wp8 advance version of internet explorer 10(IE10) use as web browser.

Answer (score 2):

It's based on Internet Explorer 10.

```
Windows Phone provides a WebBrowser control that is based on the desktop browser. 
The WebBrowser control for Windows Phone OS 7.1 is based on Internet Explorer 9, 
and the WebBrowser control for Windows Phone 8 is based on Internet Explorer 10.
```

Information from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431797%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)